# How to run pod lib lint to run xcodebuild for device only

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild, ios-frameworks

The following is the error I get while executing "pod lib lint --use-libraries --verbose".

The following build commands failed:

```
Ld /Users/Adi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dwsahfdxusxlvyeusomchjpxtele/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/App normal **i386**

Ld /Users/Adi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dwsahfdxusxlvyeusomchjpxtele/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App normal x86_64
```

From the above stack trace I understand that pod lib lint is trying to build for simulator, whereas my project has third party libraries built only for devices. Now I would like to know how to run "pod lib lint" to run xcodebuild for device only? Please help. Thanks.